# Where would I find Mac OS X sample program MoreSCF?

Tags: macos

I am playing around with SystemConfiguration on Mac OS X and in Technical Q&A QA1165 the sample code uses a macro **MoreSCError** that is supposedly define in the sample program **MoreSCF** - I can't find this sample code in the Xcode documentation or on the Apple Developer Site.

Does anyone know where I might find the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at MoreSCF.c on my machine here and it's *really old*.  The version I have is "revision 1.5" and dates from 2002.

The fact you can't easily find it on Apple's Developer Site (or Google for that matter), probably indicates that Apple would rather developers ***not*** use this code.  System Configuration framework is still very much supported on the Macintosh, but I can't think of what has replaced MoreSCF (in terms of sample code) off the top of my head.  It would likely be worth your file to find the MoreSCF replacement and work with that.

But... to help you out, I'm making the MoreSCF.h and MoreSCF.c sample code that I have available via PasteBin.  I'll set it to expire in a month so if you don't retrieve it before the end of the 30 days, you'll be S.O.L. And even though this is public, redistributable source code, if somebody asks me to remove the links (and especially if they speak up with what the newer source or sample project is), I'll remove it prior to 30 days.  These two files come out of the MoreSCF project, which has ~10 or so various C files for making System Configuration stuff easier.

Here are the links:

[MoreSCF.h](http://pastebin.com/HPRQkFEs)
[MoreSCF.c](http://pastebin.com/ALQdTzrU)

Comment: For anyone who finds this very out-of-the-way question, you should not use MoreSCF. The distribution for it now includes this:

"IMPORTANT: If your product requires Mac OS X 10.4 or later, you should use the new, high-level System Configuration framework API instead of MoreSCF.  This API, defined in the "SCNetworkConfiguration.h" header file, includes routines for doing all of things that MoreSCF does.  By using this API you make your code simpler and more future-proof."

Comment: I think I put sufficient warnings in my original answer, @shmim - but thanks for pointing out the SCNetworkConfiguration.h redirect there.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your required source code here

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/MoreSCF/Introduction/Intro.html